# No Service for Type Registered

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting the following error whenever my service gets called:

`System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type '.../.IGeneratorService' has been registered.`

Here is where I have it added: 
`Services.AddScoped<IGeneratorService, GeneratorService>();`

The generator service implements the IGeneratorService:

`public class GeneratorService : IGeneratorService`

I thought I had it setup properly but I guess I am wrong.

Comment: Change addScoped to AddTransient and see if it works?

Comment: Please can you provide a [mcve].